# flutter_tts and audioplayers together on iOs leads to flutter_tts not working as expected

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech

While playing sounds with audioplayers (https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) and using flutter_tts (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts) to say words, leads to flutter_tts not working without any error message.

I made a small example project, in there is just a few buttons to play sounds and a few buttons to use flutter_tts plugin and say some text.  https://github.com/midi1007/sound_tts

When clicking all buttons jumbled, at some point the tts plugin is not working anymore without any error message.

Does someone know how to fix this?

When using one of the two packages alone, no problems occurred, except that when using audioplayers with too high a frequency, the sound builds up and is sometimes played with a delay. Even the mode 'PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY' is not changing this issue. I played around there with low latency but no success, but this error is tolerable.

Once the tts stops working, it stops working until the app is restarted.

So one of the packages alone works, but as soon as both are used at the same time, tts stops working after a while. Sometimes it lasts for longer but sometimes it stops working right away.

Comment: You haven't included any information about what you have done to try to solve the problem.  For example, have you tried removing the audio player buttons and testing the same "jumbled" button pressing with only the tts buttons?  This would cut the problem in half.  There are also other debugging methods such as print statements which enable you to test whether what you think should be happening is actually happening.

Comment: The post is modified. I do not know what to output with print.
Do you have any idea? Is there some additional debug output especially for the tts?

Comment: Assuming that it works on Android means that it should not be a problem in your code.  You might consider sending a bug report to both of these flutter package repositories. The trouble with debugging flutter packages is that you have to understand the entire code contained in them, which defeats the purpose of using them.